# Unable to create account

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models in two different apps, the first model is a custom user model, from abstractbaseuser class, called users and the second model is called wallet the wallet model has a field account which is a foreign key to the users model.This is my problem I want to automatically create a wallet for every newly registered user but after I use this code

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save 
 from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver 
 from .models import Users
 from userwallets.models import Wallet

 @receiver(post_save, sender=Users) 
 def create_wallet(sender, created, instance, *args, **kwargs): 
     if created: 
         Wallet.objects.create(owner=instance)
```

I can only create one user then when I try to register another user it says unable to create account please what I'm doing wrong.
fyi: I'm using djoser for user registration but a customized one

I've tried anything possible no results

Comment: What is the full error you are getting?

Comment: When I try to make a post request it says unable to create account

Answer (score -1):

Edit: I fixed it by removing the unique tag in the wallet id field of my wallet model because the library I used was encountering an integrity error